# XAMPP MySQL Database Copy

Tags: mysql, xampp

I had to format my Mac as updating OSX Crashed. I had the backup of the XAMPP folder on my disk. Is there a way I can copy some files to the newly installed XAMPP folder and get all databases back?

Do I make any sense?

> I tried copying all folder but XAMPP failed to start throwing `Requires Admin Privileges`

Note: I have no recent **.sql** backup of the databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once had the same problem. It's not that complicated.

Just copy the folders of database to `XAMPP/var/mysql/`

That's all.

Comment: there is no XAMPP/war

Comment: for Mac: Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql